# jQuery Bootstrap form validation

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I've got two separate forms on a page which only displays one at a time and you have to fill in the required fields and click next to get to the next form (step). The next buttons are disabled to prevent moving forward without completing the necessary info.

My issue is I can't figure out how to modify my existing code in order to remove the "disabled" attribute from the second button after the second form is validated.

Currently my code removes the disabled attribute from both at the same time which is not the desired outcome.

jQuery:

```
$(".form-control").change(function(event) {

// Fetch form to apply custom Bootstrap validation
var form = $("#shippingCHKOut, #ccPaymentInfo")

if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
} else {
    $('button#shippingOK').removeAttr("disabled"); // button on first form
    $('button#paymentOK').removeAttr("disabled");  // button on second form
}

form.addClass('was-validated');

});
```

Comment: You can solve it by doing some research on google.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of reading and tinkering I guess I came across a solution that works well enough for what I need. I'll leave it here if anyone comes across a similar situation.

```
$(".form-control").change(function(event) {

// Fetch form to apply custom Bootstrap validation
var form = $("#ccPaymentFields, #shippingCHKOut")

if (form[0].checkValidity() === false)  {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
} 

form.addClass('was-validated');
// Perform ajax submit here...


if ($('form#shippingCHKOut input:invalid').length > 0 ) {
    $('button#shippingOK').attr('disabled');
} else {
    $('button#shippingOK').removeAttr('disabled');
}

if ($('form#ccPaymentFields input:invalid').length > 0 ) {
    $('button#paymentOK').attr('disabled');
} else {
    $('button#paymentOK').removeAttr('disabled');
}    

});
```